# Downloading picasa album and photos

Tags: download, picasa

I would like to download Picasa album and photos using a program.
What should I do?

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Your question is a little vague. Are you trying to write a program for this? Are you looking a program that does this?

Comment: yes i am trying to write a program in java. I want to download all images for a specified album and save it to my local disk.
I need a downloadable link for this. The general picassa album url will give me html in response. I need a downloadable link which should return image bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [Picasa Web Albums Data API](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/picasaweb/code.html).
There are many clients available in different languages such:

1. Java
2. .NET
3. PHP
4. Python
5. Objective-C